How would a buddhist respond to the following criticism of the Buddhist philosophy in the Mrgendra Agama?
The Mrgendra Agama, A Saivite Hindu Agama text, in a certain chapter pertaining to the refutation of Rival schools makes the following criticism of the Buddhist position -

cidyavañjakasya karmādeḥ kṣaṇikatvānmuhurmuhuḥ| vyajyate jāyamāneva
kṣaṇike matā paraiḥ|| 24
Due to the functions and operations of those instruments which help
for the manifestation of consciousness, cit (knowledge) appears to be
momentary, since those functions are of fractional duration. Not
knowing this, the Saugatas say that consciousness is momentary.
tadasatkarmaṇo bhogādātītānubhavasmṛteḥ| sthitirinanvaye nāśe na
smṛternāpi karmaṇaḥ|| 25||
vināśa lakṣaṇopaiti na muktāvapyupaplavaḥ| na cāstyanubhavaḥ kaścit
bhāvāvasthā varaṃ tataḥ|| 26||
This view of momentariness is untenable. If consciousness itself is
momentary, the experience of meritorious and sinful effects and the
remembrance of previous experiences cannot occur. Because
consciousness which occurs at one moment perishes at the next moment
itself. How could the effect of karmas done by one man be experienced
by another man?
Or, how could the experience attained by one man be
remembered by another man? Because of the ascertained occurrence of
the karmic effects and remembrance, it is to be deduced that the self
is essentially eternal; not momentary.
There is another defect in the
concept of momentariness of the self. Can the occurrence of
uninterrupted continuity of momentary-self be considered as
liberation? Or, can the pacified and stilled state of consciousness
itself after knowing the object, just like the extinguished beam of a
lamp, be considered as the state of liberation? If it is the case of
former, then, even in the state of liberation, the continuity of the
momentary self frequently gets destroyed. If it is the case of latter,
then, there is no experience of bliss in the extinguished state of the
self. Therefore, when compared to this kind of blissless liberation,
"to be enmeshed in the transmigratory phenomena" is more preferable;
more superior.

~ Mrgendra Agama, Vidya Pada, 2.24-26
How would a Buddhist respond to this critique philosophically?

How could the effect of karmas done by one man be experienced by another man?, this postulation (A) totally lost me. How did the author use momentary consciousness to go off tangent to reach this? Then the author refuted postulation A and deduced that conclusion B that the self is eternal must be true! Am I  missing or not seeing a link here? Sorry I am not versed in Mrgendra Agama.

In the first paragraph the Mrgendra Agama conceives 'momentary' as equivalent to 'fractional duration'. In other words, it portrays the Buddhist conception of consciousness as though consciousness jumps across fractionally small (perhaps infinitely small) moments of time, ceasing to exist in one moment and then reappearing in the next next. The argument is a bit like Zeno's Paradox, interestingly…
However, this argument retains time as a linear sequence of moments, which isn't what Buddhist philosophy holds. In Buddhism, consciousness exists (eternally, sort of) in this moment, and time is illusory. Experiences arise in this moment and fade away in this moment; thoughts of the past (memories) and thoughts of the future (anticipations) arise and fade in this moment; interactions with others arise and fade in this moment. All of this arising and fading gives an impression of time passing, and attachments to those arisings and fadings solidify that impression as 'fact'. This solidified 'fact-ness' creates karma: events continually reappear in this moment because our clinging creates a pivot that swings them back and forth through the illusion of time.
But this 'fact-ness' merely obscures the timeless 'this-moment-ness' of consciousness.
To the last point, liberation comes when we perceive the illusion of time for what it is. When we understand that it is our own clinging that causes events to come back and haunt us in some illusory time, then we can release the clinging and cease to be haunted, escaping karma. The Mrgendra Agama again tries to cast 'this-moment-ness' as the destruction of consciousness in linear time, when in fact the dissolution of (imagined) linear time is what brings us into resonance with consciousness in this moment.
Ultimately, a buddhist is likely to say that the Mrgendra Agama is an expression of the thinking mind trying to maintain itself as a 'fact'. The thinking mind (the self, the identity) exists to remember, to anticipate, and to cope with perceived events in the perceived flow of time. When we touch on 'this-moment-ness', the thinking mind is exposed to itself as a mere appearance among other appearances, and can only interpret that in terms of death or loss or absence. The thinking mind is troubled by 'this-moment-ness' and tries to reject it, preferring the flow of karma where it knows it has a purpose. When we get past that we can experience 'this-moment-ness' exactly as it is, and that is its own reward.

Consciousness is impermanent. Consciousness arises , changes while persisting and vanishes.
Consciousness is a Sankhara. Consciousness is a conditioned phenomena. Consciousness arises due to combination of phenomena. Consciousness changes and vanishes due to combination or separation of phenomena.
Sometimes consciousness of something can be momentary or be present over vast expanse of time. The consciousness of this moment is not same as the consciousness of the past moment nor is it entirely different.
Karma occurs due to ignorance and cravings. Consciousness plays its part in all the acts of karma. Consciousness does not necessarily appear and vanish with every moment. But this doesn’t mean that consciousness is self and it is eternal.
Consciousness is Anatta (not self)because
Consciousness is impermanent. That which is impermanent is the cause of suffering. That which is suffering can not be called Self.
Nibbana or liberation is also Anatta. Nibbana is not me , mine or myself.
The search is not for blissfulness but removal of suffering which is the result of ignorance and cravings.


In the teachings of the Buddha, consciousness is merely sense experience arising dependent upon a sense organ & a sense object. Thus as mentioned in many places (such as in MN 38, SN 22.53 & SN 12.67), in Buddhism, there can be no arising/occurring of consciousness independent of sense organs, sense objects, mind-body (nama-rupa) and the other four aggregates. MN 43 explicitly explains when perception & feeling end, consciousness ends, and all that remains is a living physical body.

The experience of meritorious and sinful effects and the remembrance of previous experiences is not related to consciousness (which is mere sense experience). Memory is not consciousness. Memory is merely a sense object of consciousness. The results (psycho-physical impacts) of kamma are not stored in consciousness. The Buddha taught there are five aggregates, namely, body, feeling, perception, mental formations & consciousness. While the Buddha did not offer any analysis about what is 'memory', in Buddhism, memories & effects of past actions are related to what are called 'anusaya' ('underlying tendencies'). These underlying tendencies are part of the aggregate of mental formations (which are stored in the nervous system of the physical body). They are not related to the aggregate of consciousness.

The Buddha never taught about the occurrence of uninterrupted continuity of momentary-self as liberation.


However, to conclude, the mentioned Hindu attacks upon 'Buddhism' appear certainly based upon corruptions of Buddhism. The later heretical Buddhism which continues today as mainstream Buddhism (called 'Theravada' & 'Mahayana') do teach about consciousness independent of physical body and 'storehouse consciousness' that carries kammic imprints. These are examples of how easily Hinduism debunked the later mainstream corruptions of Buddhism, which includes Abhidhamma, which made the terms 'citta' ('mind-heart') & 'vinnana' ('consciousness') synonymous.
The Hindu attacks upon Buddhism simply resemble current debates on Buddhist chatsites among Buddhists. In short, Buddhism destroyed itself in India. It was not Hinduism or Islam that destroyed Buddhism in India. The Buddha taught:


Let none find fault with others; let none see the omissions and commissions of others. But let one see one's own acts, done and
undone.



As I had commented that the author’s postulation that one man can experienced the karmic effect of another as a result of momentary consciousness is highly dubious. It is likely a result of A) a fecund imagination or B) a misunderstanding of what momentary consciousness is about.
Ignoring possibility (A), the misunderstanding of (B) is likely due to the lack of experiential data due to not putting into practice the Buddha’s teachings. When we practise anatta or not-self while observing and being mindful of form, feeling, perception, mental formation and consciousness, we can penetrate into the real nature of these aggregates.
Unlike the “consciousness without surface” mentioned in MN 49 and alluded in various sutra such as SN35:23, our consciousness is limited, constrained and tainted by cravings. The cravings for sensual pleasures, for becoming and for not-becoming. It is this constrained consciousness, tainted with cravings that cognizes in moments, “Ah, this a joyful moment”, “That is bad one” or “This is a boring time”?
It is desiring that anticipates the next moment and coloured our next consciousness. What would it be like if the mind is able to stop this desiring from influencing the next conscious moment? I believe this is what the Buddha wanted us to experience for ourselves. (Caution: criticisms from here on).
Reading the OP’s posted section of Mrgendra Agama and how the author deduced that the self is essentially eternal and connecting this to Advaita Vedanta philosophy of jivatman, Atman and Brahman; I can’t help but feel that Hindu India had gone in a diametrically opposite direction from that prescribed by the Buddha.
In Buddhism, the atta or atman or self or soul is wrong view, period. To then augment and glorify it until it reaches a grandiose, eternal and universal Atman or Brahman that is formless, partless and unperceivable; appeared to be a dodgy way of preventing too many questions from being asked. To help his followers overcome this instinctive grasping towards a self-view, the Buddha came up with the teaching of anatta i.e. not-self. In Advaita, Anatman (or anatta) is instead used to realise Atman!?
Wrong views do have consequences which is also the reason why the Buddha put in a lot of efforts and more than half his life to correct them. A sand castle, no matter how grandiose and tall, eventually crumbles with the rising tide.

Addendum 1 (added to answer OP's comment)
Whether non-dualist (Advaita), qualified non-dualist (Visistha) or dualist (Dvaita), there is an assumption that the eternal Self/Soul/Atman (Brahman) existed. It is a self hypothesis that has 2 major flaws. One, the definition of self cannot be tested as it is formless and unperceivable i.e. it is unobservable and unmeasurable. Two, the data needed to support this hypothesis i.e. proof that it is true, cannot be gathered! Brahman created this universe and prior universes; we can’t even gather information of prior universes, let alone the first instance of a universe created by Brahman!
Contrast this with the Buddha’s null hypothesis of not-self (anatta). The definition of self by the Buddha is strict; it must be non-changing and perfectly controllable. By observing form (our physical body), feeling, perception, mental formation and consciousness, we can see that these are in a constant flux and not always within our control i.e. not-self. Thus, we can begin gathering data to either proof or refute this not-self hypothesis. We can perform this test on both ourselves and others; in fact, data from any observable and measurable phenomena can be used to test this hypothesis.
If we study science or statistics, we know the Atman/Brahman hypothesis is useless because it is unprovable and not even testable!

Mrgendra Agama is actually a dualist text. In it's refutation of rival schools, it makes arguments  against the Nondualist version of vedanta as well.

@SupremeVoid I added an addendum to point out the fundamental problem with all these Hindu philosophies.
